# Google Places Activity API

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Google has launched the ability to determine the activity of a restaurant like so: https://support.google.com/business/answer/6263531?hl=en

Is there an API available where this data can be accessed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Popular times are not available at the moment via API. There is a feature request for Popular times in the public issue tracker:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35827350

Hopefully it will be available in the future. The feature request has more than 400 stars, I believe Google should take this into account and prioritize the task at some point.